# Does it make sense to talk about "frequency" when expanding a function using spherical harmonics?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, spherical-harmonics

If I had a function defined in the sphere and I expand it using spherical harmonics, such as

$$
f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} c_{lm}Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$

does it make any sense to talk about "low frequency" and "high frequency"? If yes, what is usually meant by that?

My analogy is with the Fourier analysis where low frequency is usually associated wit the first terms of a series. I think something similar can be said here, is it correct?

Comment: You can talk about bandwidth of a function by means of the Laplacian in the sphere. More precisely, you can say that the "frequency" of $f$ is $[0,\lambda]$ if it is spanned by the eigenfunctions of the Laplcian of eigenvalues up to $\lambda$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more in a complete answer please?

Comment: I never seen it before, but I would probably get the analogy, and expect that it refers to the number of nodes / zero-crossings the function has. There may also be other quantities the would do the same job, like "principal quantum number", or some measure of energy (an $L^2$-norm of a spatial derivative?) if you like physics, or you could just talk about lower/higher eigenvalues if you prefer, like @pipenauss suggests, if you want to stay in math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a uniform string stretched between $-L$ and $L$. The wave equation for this is
$$
                           u_{tt}=cu_{xx},\;\;\; u(t,\pm L)=0, c >0.
$$
The resonant, or characteristic, frequencies of the string are the eigenvalues of the operator $Df = cf''$ subject to $f(\pm L)=0$. For any such $f$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, there is a stationary (standing wave) solution of the wave equation
$$
                     f(x)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t+\phi).
$$
The string has evenly spaced $\sqrt{\lambda}$.

If you have a spherical balloon of radius $1$, then the wave equation is
$$
                u_{tt}=c\Delta_S u,
$$
where $\Delta_S$ is the Laplacian on the sphere. The stationary solutions correspond to the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator on the sphere, and the frequency of this solution is proportional to $\sqrt{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the spherical Laplacian. There are the natural resonant frequencies of the balloon. The spherical harmonics are the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on the unit spherical shell, and these are the displacement distributions of the natural resonant modes.

The spherical harmonics are the eigenfunctions of the spherical Laplacian:
$$
          \Delta_S Y_{l}^{m}(\theta,\varphi)= -l(l+1)Y_{l}^{m}.
$$
The corresponding frequencies in $t$ are $\sqrt{l(l+1)}$, which are not evenly spaced, and one of the reasons an excited balloon does not sound very musical. And there are multiple shapes for the given $l$, and these all have the same natural frequency. The displacements of the natural shapes are described by the spherical harmonics, and the frequency of their oscillations when excited is given as a constant times the square root of the eigenvalue.

http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/ClassicalWaveEquations1.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Comment: Probably using L for both the differential operator and the length of the interval is not a good idea ;-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : Than you. I agree, and have fixed that.

Comment: And again... if $f$ is a "low frequency" this means the first say $N$ terms of the expansion in spherical harmonics are not zero in general, all the other ones are zero. I see correspondence between this and your eigenvalue argument.

Comment: I re-read your answer. makes sense to me. Kind of saying that $f_n(t) = e^{int}$ are eigen functions of the differential operator $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}.$ Indeed we have $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f_n = -n^2 f_n $$, the laplacian operator would be the equivalent of the such operator.